# IE11 not showing the same on port

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

It's hard to write a subject for this question so I'll just lay it down.

- Open IE11 Preview and go to bing.com.
- Open the dev tools (F12).
- Write the following in the javascript console.

```js
var p = document.createElement('a');  
p.href = "http://bing.com";  
p.port;
```

- You'll see that `p.port` returns `"80"`
- But if you then write `location.port` you'll see the return is an empty string `""`

I have no idea what the correct answer should be, but I would expect to get the same value for `p.port` and `location.port`.

Is this a bug? Am I missing anything?

TIA

**Edit**: My question is simple, why `p.port` and `location.port` return different values when they are targeted (refed) to the exact same url?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this page on the Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.location#Properties), since port 80 is the default port, `location.port` returns an empty string. It only returns a value if the port isn't the default port.

Comment: MDN is much better IMO, here's the link to location properties with the proper information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.location#Properties

Comment: Spamming w3fools on SO is easy, but comparing those two pages W3Schools has the answer to this question, the MDN page doesn't.

Comment: I understand @Charlie, but in the case of `p.port` it is also the default, but instead of returning "" (empty string) it returns 80

Comment: Right, but `p.port` is an object representing an `<a>` element in the DOM. It is not the same type of object as `location`. They both have `href` and `port` properties, but the values returned by `port` are subtly different in this way.

Comment: I agree with Christoph and @jlafay's criticism. W3schools isn't a great source, and by citing it I lend it authority that it doesn't deserve. Fortunately, the MDN is also a wiki, so I was able to edit the documentation there to be more clear. I've updated my answer with the MDN link.

Comment: According to this answer and this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh770784.aspx I believe `p.port` should be returning "" instead of 80, so I guess it is a bug